# pmdarima auto_arima always suggest same p d q order

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, arima, pmdarima

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

today = date.today()

d1 = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = d1
d2 = date.today() - timedelta(days=365)
d2 = d2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
start_date = d2

data = yf.download('INTC',
                      start=start_date,
                      end=end_date,
                      progress=False)
data["Date"] = data.index
data = data[["Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Adj Close", "Volume"]]
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(data.tail())

data = data[["Date", "Close"]]
print(data.head())


model = auto_arima(data["Close"],
                      test='adf',
                      seasonal=True,
                      trace=True, D=1,d=1,
                      error_action='ignore',
                      suppress_warnings=True,
                      stepwise=True)
model.summary()
```

This code block I use for deciding  p d q order, and it seems whenever I change the dataset, by using `yfinance` it gives the same order,

I tried to decompose the data and it has a sesonality.

[image: We can see it also has a trend]
We can see it also has a trend.

The problem I suspect is with differencing, when i use this code:

```
data['Diff'] = data['Close'] - data['Close'].shift(1)
```

It says the  p,d,q order is 0,0,0 so it just chagned the 0,1,0. Wonder what is the problem.

Comment: I added a simple repo, yeah i know that random walks are hard to predict ,i have no plans for using this to get rich ,but it seems with R i get better results, i mean in R it dosent just say arima order 0,1,0 to every stock data.